# How sweep_all without prompt in CLI?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, sweep-transaction

I want run sweep_all command, but I don't want entering password or press "Y" (when prompt).
[image]

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be:

```
set ask-password 0
set always-confirm-transfers 0
```